# Failed to read module directory

Tags: azure, module, terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a folder structure in the below format

```
demo
   proj
     terraform
       myfile.tf
```

The modules are present in the below path

```
demo
   modules
     terraform
       myconfigfiles
         vmcreation
```

How do I call the modules in terraform. The path of the source is not working. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
source = "../modules/terraform/myconfigfiles/vmcreation"
```

I am getting this error during terraform init

```
Error: Unreadable module directory
│ 
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: CreateFile ..\modules: The system
│ cannot find the file specified.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to read module directory
│ 
│ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Also the `source = ...` line is inside of the `myfile.tf` file?

Comment: Yes the source= is inside the myfile.tf and I am using windows OS. I am trying to execute the code using yaml pipeline like this

workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/demo/proj/terraform'

Comment: I have a feeling Matt's answer is correct.

Comment: And where are you using the `workingDirectory`? Is that some kind of a variable?

Comment: workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/demo/proj/terraform'

Comment: If the folder structure is going to be like this how to reference the source parameter

demo
   proj
     terraform
         data
             myfile.tf

Will it be source = "../../../modules/terraform/myconfigfiles/vmcreation" or am I missing anything again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative pathing between the root module config and the declared module requires another `..` prefix:

```
source = "../../modules/terraform/myconfigfiles/vmcreation"
```

Comment: If the folder structure is going to be like this how to reference the source parameter

demo
   proj
     terraform
         data
             myfile.tf

Will it be source = "../../../modules/terraform/myconfigfiles/vmcreation" or am I missing anything again